# How do i put my typing script outside my html file?

Tags: javascript, html, typed

I have my site, with a script that types out an array of things after a `h2` in a `span`.

First I had to include the script in the html file, the whole js script, which is too long and too useless within the html file also.
So I tried to get it outside of my html file, and include it, like this.

```
<script src="javascript/index.js"></script>
```

But then nothing happens with my `span`

```
<h2>I am <span id="typing"></span></h2>
```

And this is my index.js

```
var typed = new Typed('#typing', {
    strings: ['first thing', 'second thing'],
    typeSpeed: 30,
    loop: true
});
```

Comment: can you take a picture of your file directory and post it with this question?

Comment: Can you press f12 and show is the console error, if there is any? I think you just don't import the file correctly. I assume you will see a 404 telling you that the resource wasn't found.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null
    at t.value (typed.min.js:10)
    at new t (typed.min.js:10)
    at index.js:3" I also imported the library via html, is that a problem?

Comment: So its importing correctly and trying to use typed.min.js. This it where it fails. Are you sure you are using that function correctly? I think it doesnt find the element with id typed in your dom. Can you show the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the dom to be loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var typed = new Typed('#typing', {
      strings: ['first thing', 'second thing'],
      typeSpeed: 30,
      loop: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah this! Quick thinking ;)

Comment: Happy to hear it works! Could you accept the answer if your problem is solved?